# How to swap a specific weapon for a new weapon during a supply drop in MGSV: TPP

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I currently have two primary weapons equipped. I want to change one of these primary weapons for a different weapon. I order a supply drop, and this arrives. How do I specify which of my two primary weapons should be replaced by the new weapon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two primary slots are for different types of weapons. The first is for your rifles, shotguns etc. and the second is for your heavy weapons such as the sniper rifles, machine guns and launchers.

If your supply drop is a heavy weapon it will replace your current heavy, otherwise it will replace your primary in the first slot.

Comment: Thanks for clarification: I was using a grenade launcher, which went in the first slot but meant I was a bit underequipped when dealing with enemy soldiers. Will see what suitable weapons I can develop that go into the second slot...

Comment: @Jim On a side note, you should take a look into alternate solutions for grenade launchers. If you don't use pistols much, the Zorn KP is a pistol that fires grenades, similar to a rifle grenade. And once you recover the Legendary Gunsmith, and get access to weapon customization, you can develop two of the single-shot grenade launchers to be mounted underbarrel on any weapon with an underbarrel attachment option.